# How to make a pattern that uses the formula and the value of the same cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-forms

I want to create a model where I can add numbers to that specific column and it will return a string concatenating a string and the value put in the cell.

Example:
When writing a value 123 to the cell, it will return a string say "http:// www.link.com/" concatenated with the value of the value 123 (as string).

Resulting -> http:// www.link.com/123

Comment: You cannot do it in the same cell, you can only concatenate them together in another cell using a formula as brgsousa's answer.

Comment: Oh :/ alright then, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the operand **&**

For example, use this formula the result cell:

> ="http:// ww.link.com/"&A1

It will use A1 cell value to concatenate to your string

Comment: Thanks, that's not exactly what I wanted, but it helped me after! :)